# Using JavaScript code entered into a textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

I want to create a `<textarea>`, and I want to use JavaScript code which is entered into the `<textarea>`, as code.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the value of the textarea through the [javascript `eval()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp), causing them to be evaluated as javascript.

Online example: http://jsbin.com/ohuqa/edit

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that you want to have the contents of the `<textarea>` parsed and evaluated as Javascript, you'd do something like this:

```
var script = document.getElementById('theIdOfTheTextarea').value;
eval(script);
```

You'd probably want to wrap that in a try/catch so that you could display an error:

```
try {
  eval(script);
}
catch (e) {
  alert("Error in the codes: " + e);
}
```